# React conditional style on custom click

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am trying to change a class when `onClick` event is fired, my function is called and it seems to be working but the class just won't update un the render, this is my code:

```
import React from 'react';

const Something = props => {
  let opened = false;

  const toggle = () => {
    opened = !opened;
  };

  return (
    <div className={opened ? 'some-class opened' : 'some-class'}>
      <div className="some-inner-class" onClick={toggle}>
       ...content
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Something;
```

I just want to be able to change style on when click event is fired.

Comment: Just define `opened` value as state to rerender your component when it is changed. and use this.setState function to update it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion to you will be to use react hooks in this scenario, by that I mean, something like this, I have updated your code with my suggestion;
Hope it helps;

```
import React, { useState }  from 'react';

const Something = props => {
  // ***because this doesn't exist in a function component and we'd want to persist this value of opened between function call, a react hook in a function component will be ideal in your case. 
  //let opened = false; 

  // *suggestion as per react documentation: useState hook lets us keep local state in a function component
  const [opened, setOpened] = useState(false);

  // ***you don't really need this part, see my approach in second div of return 
  // const toggle = () => {
  //   opened = !opened;
  // };

  return (
    <div className={opened ? 'some-class opened' : 'some-class'}>
      <div className="some-inner-class" onClick={() => setOpened(true)}>
        <p>Click me</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Something;
```

Comment: This is great help, after adapting this code I did this:
 ```onClick={!opened ? () => setOpened(true) : () => setOpened(false)}```
in order to return `opened` to its previous state, not sure if this is the best practice to do it but it is working.

Answer (score 1):

You need to update state in React for a rerender to occur. You should be creating state in a constructor like:

```
constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = { toggled: false };
}
```

Then, in your toggle function you need to call

```
this.setState({toggled: !this.state.toggled});
```

Currently your component is a stateless functional component so you would either need to rewrite it as a class that extends `React.component` or you could use hooks, https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html. Since it looks like you're just starting to learn how to use React I would rewrite the component as a class first and then try to refactor it using hooks (the modern practice).

Comment: Thanks, you're correct, I'm kind of new to react and sure I will follow your advice.